# Algebraically closed field s.t. $K\simeq L$, $K\subsetneq L$.

Tags: field-theory, examples-counterexamples

Are there algebraically closed fields $K$ and $L$ that satisfy $K\simeq L$ and $K\subsetneq L$?

Comment: Yes. Complex numbers have a lot subfields isomorphic to itself. Infinitely many in fact.

Comment: @freakish Could you give me one example?

Comment: Take transcendental basis $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since it is uncountable then there is an injective but not surjective function $f:S\to S$. This function extends to field homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(S)\to\mathbb{Q}(S)$, which then extends to field homomorphism $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. But it remains injective and not surjective.

Comment: This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Comment: First you tell people how to ask and answer question. Then what you even can ask or answer. And now how to comment. Amazing, what a great site.

Comment: It's not about me or my actions. Please have a look at the linked documentation what comments are for and why they should not be used for posting answers. It's not my opinion, it's site policy (for good reasons). See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559 for some discussion.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm not talking about *you* personally. And perhaps I wasn't clear enough: I don't care about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples. Any two algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic and the same uncountable cardinality are isomorphic (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562735/two-algebraically-closed-fields-with-char-0-and-same-cardinality-kappa-al)). Hence, for any uncountable algebraically closed field $K$ there is an isomorphism between $K$ and $\overline{K(T)}$, and of course that contains $K$.