How to prove that two algebraically closed field with same characteristic and cardinal are isomorphic?
Hi I would like to prove that for algebraic closed field $F_1,F_2$ if:

They have the same characteristic $p$
They have the same cardinal and is uncountable

Then they are isomorphic.
I have proved that with the same characteristic $F_1,F_2$ has isomorphic sub-field, donate $F'$, and $F_1,F_2$ are vector space over $F'$
I think the next step is to expend the isomorphic mapping from the sub-field to the whole field but I stucked in this and cannot find a way.

It's possible for $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be isomorphic but for no isomorphism to preserve $F$. Take the algebraic closure of $F=F_1=\mathbb{Q}$ adjoin countably many elements and $F_2$ be the algebraic closure of $F_1(X)$. They both have the same characteristic and transcendence degree, so are isomorphic, but $F=F_1 \subset F_2$ so the isomorphism cannot restrict to the identity on $F$.

@zoeallen Thanks a lot! In that case how should I prove that if $F_1,F_2$ has the same characteristic and cardinal, they are isomorphic????

You need to pick a transcendence basis and build the isomorphism from a bijection of the transcendence bases.

@zoeallen could you tell where I can find the detailed prove?? Thanks a lot

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3623568/1107685 covers the finite degree case, and the infinite degree case is much the same. I don't have a link for the infinite case.

@zoeallen thanks a lot! I've read this post, but this is the other way around which trying to prove that if two algebraic closed field is isomorphic, then the isomorphic mapping preserves the transcendence base

Here is another duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2562735/7062
